# How can I rank a input list and assign it a variable to return to user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a hard time with my program and my code skills are quite elementary. What I need to do is take an inputted list from the user and rank them by letter A (66 - 100), B (33 - 65), C (0 - 32). I assume I need the inputted list to be a tuple but I'm not entirely sure how to do so. I know I need to (or can) use an elif to accomplish this but I'm not sure how to make it a range between two numbers for B since C is else, and A is just greater than. 
This is my code:

```
def scores():
    print('we are starting')
    count = int(input('Enter amount of scores: '))
    print('Each will be entered one per line')
    scoreList = []
    for i in range(1, count+1):
            scoreList.append(int(input('Enter score: ')))
            print(scoreList)
    print(scoreList)
    if scoreList > 66:
        print('A')
    #elif scoreList > 33:
        #print('B')
    else:
        print ('C')
```

Comment: `score` does not exist in your code.

Comment: @poke , thanks I forgot to put "List" in the score variable.

Comment: Well, in that case: `scoreList` is a list of numbers while `66` (and `33`) is just a number; you cannot compare these. You will have to do something with your list first, or iterate through it and check every single value inside.

Answer (score 0):

Just chain together your conditions using logical operators (`and`, `or`, `not`) and loop through each item in the list:

```
def scores():
    print('we are starting')
    count = int(input('Enter amount of scores: '))
    print('Each will be entered one per line')
    scoreList = []
    for i in range(1, count+1):
            scoreList.append(int(input('Enter score: ')))
            print(scoreList)
    print(scoreList)
    for score in scoreList:
        if score >= 66:
            print('A')
        elif score >= 35 and score <=65:
            print('B')
        else:
            print('C')
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for the if-structure:

```
for score in scoreList:
    if 66 <= score <= 100:
        print('A')
    elif 33 <= score <= 65:
        print('B')
    elif 0 <= score <= 32:
        print('C')
    else:
        # handle out of range input
```

This way you can use the `else` to handle input that isn't between `0` and `100`.

Comment: `if score >= 66 … elif score >= 33 … else …` is actually the same if you can assume that the value of `score` is between `0` and `100`.

Comment: The value of `score` comes from the user - and humans make mistakes all the time.

Comment: That is true, but unless you add some smart `else` to your solution, accepting values beyond the range is a better idea than failing silently ;)

Comment: Thank you, I will add that to my answer.